# How do I create a loop in python that advances on a key press with an exit command?

Tags: python, loops

So, I am working on a basic calculator. It needs to keep being able to do new calculations when I press a key to advance it, but when I type `close` into the operator. The code should explain this better.

```
a=2
if a==2:

    l = int(input("Enter the left side of the equation: "))
    r = int(input("Enter the right side of the equation: "))
    o = input("Enter the operator: ")
    if o=="close":
        break
    
    from time import sleep

    import operator
    ops = { "+": operator.add, "-": operator.sub, "*": operator.mul, "/": operator.truediv, "abs": operator.abs, "%": operator.mod } # etc.

    print (ops[o](l,r))

    import os
    os.system("pause")


print("Closing in 3")
sleep(1)
print("Closing in 2")
sleep(1)
print("Closing in 1")
sleep(1)
```

So yeah. That's what I've tried, but it just exits immediately when I run it now.

The `a=2` deal was just an easy way for me to make a loop.

Comment: with if a == 2 you are not creating a loop. You can directly replace that by "while true:"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `if a==2` to `while a==2`:

```
a=2
while a==2:

    l = int(input("Enter the left side of the equation: "))
    r = int(input("Enter the right side of the equation: "))
    o = input("Enter the operator: ")
    if o=="close":
        break
    
    from time import sleep

    import operator
    ops = { "+": operator.add, "-": operator.sub, "*": operator.mul, "/": operator.truediv, "abs": operator.abs, "%": operator.mod } # etc.

    print (ops[o](l,r))

    import os
    os.system("pause")


print("Closing in 3")
sleep(1)
print("Closing in 2")
sleep(1)
print("Closing in 1")
sleep(1)
```